# Android TCP socket doesn't receive data

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am using Android app to communicate, send and receive messages through TCP socket with a PC java application on the same LAN. Below is the code of Asynctask i am using in android to send a message and receive a reply from PC:

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

Context context;
String dstAddress;
int dstPort;
String msg;

Client(Context context, String addr, int port, String msg) {
    this.context = context;
    dstAddress = addr;
    dstPort = port;
    this.msg = msg;
}

String reply = "";

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        BufferedWriter dout = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream() ));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        //send request
        dout.write(msg);
        dout.flush();
        dout.close();

        //get response
        reply = br.readLine();
        br.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // DISPLAY REPLY CONTENT
    Handler handler =  new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    handler.post( new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Server reply: " + reply ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

- I am displaying the reply of the PC in a toast in onPostExcecute.
- Android sends the message through BufferedWriter, while the java app on PC receives it in a BufferedReader. (working fine, and tested)
- The PC sends a response throught a BufferedWriter to the android after receiving the message, where the android receives the reply in a BufferedReader as shown: br.readLine(). (HERE is the problem): According to the PC's app debug the reply is sent successfully without any IOExceptions or errors happening, But at the android side the reply string is empty, looks like it received nothing. I really don't know what am I doing wrong, and hope someone can point out to what i am missing.

Below is the server's thread that handles a client socket, the thread runs basically whenever serversocket accepts a socket:

```
static class clientThread extends Thread {

    Socket s = null;
    clientThread(Socket s) //constructor
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())); //receiving data into a buffered reader

            String dataIn = br.readLine(); // reading the buffered data into a string
                System.out.println("received: " + dataIn);

            //BufferedWriter dout = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            //dout.write("OK");
            //dout.newLine();

            PrintWriter dout = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())), true);
            if(dataIn.equals("Android client"))
            {
                dout.println("OK");
                dout.flush();
                System.out.println("OK sent");
            }


            dout.close();
            br.close();
            s.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { System.out.println("Error occured"); }

    }
}
```

SO to sum up the programs, the android sends the message "Android client" (Which the server receives and prints on the console with no issues), now with the reply, the server sends "OK" with no issues as well, but android side receives nothing.
ALSO, as i mentioned before, if i remove 
        dout.close();
from android's asynctask after i send the message, the server receives the message ONLY when the program gets terminated, I dont understand why i have to close it in order for the message to be sent successfully.

Comment: Please show the server code too.

Comment: You do not need that hand!er in onPostExecute(). You can directly call that Toast().

Comment: `dout.close();`. Remove that line. It closes the socket.

Comment: In that catch block place `reply = "UnknownHostException: " + e.getMessage();`. Something similar for the others.

Comment: I am sorry, correct me if i am wrong: dout.close() closes the bufferedwriter, while the socket itself closes at socket.close() line after the try body is executed, right? And early i suspected that closing the bufferedwriter could be the issue but when i removed it early this morning the appwas connecting to server but the message was sent only when the app is closed/terminated. PS: updating the post with server code as soon as o can, in the next few hours. Thanks for your response and patience.

Comment: You are wrong. Closing either the input stream or the output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.

Comment: We cannot see what the client sends to the server. Please add that in your code. We cannot see what the server sends to the client. But it should be a line as the client tries to read a line.

Comment: This code wil incur a `SocketException: Socket closed`. Why haven't you mentioned it?

Comment: The message the server sends has to end with a newline, because you are using `readLine()` on Android side.

Comment: I added the server's code: a thread that handles any connecting socket after being accepted by a serversocket. Overall I feel like the issue is that i am closing stuff i shouldn't be. Looking forward for your help, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading lines but you aren't sending lines. Add a line terminator to the message sent by the client, or use `BufferedWriter.newLine()`; and `flush()` instead of closing the buffered writer.

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot man. I didn't have to close dout by creating a newline in order for the message to be received by server, thus the socket wasn't closed.. leading to the buffered reader at android side to read the reply. Again, thanks a lot, I didn't know closing a buffered reader/writer closes the socket as well.